# Force PHP to display only existing images

Tags: php, image, web-crawler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find if an image exists, or renders ok issue in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301174/how-to-find-if-an-image-exists-or-renders-ok-issue-in-php)

This PHP crawler:

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.11) Gecko/2009060215 Firefox/3.0.11'); #disguise as a bot

for ($i = 1; $i <= 25000; $i++) { 
    echo "<img src='http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/3809_obj_sprite.gif?id=" . $i . "' onerror='this.src =\"n.png\";'/>";
    usleep(1); #it ufreezes my box a little
}
```

Shows up 25k-1 images.

**How to force PHP to show only existing images**? And I can not use `file_exist` becaouse its on remote host.

Comment: image_size is not for remote hosts mate and their solutions are A. Broken or B. to solow

Comment: Well image_size in this case works but its even slower than headers. Maybe I shall rewrite output in JS to show only good images?